# Defending against magic

Tags: magic, military-defense

I'm writing a short story about a man who faces off against a Necromancer, and am wondering what sort of defenses the main character and/or his party might employ against the Necromancer's magic.

I would call the general setting of the story **hard fantasy** - magic exists, but few are able to practice it and even fewer are interested in doing so. The story takes place in roughly the 14th century (think Black Plague, English Longbow, Hundred Years' War). Otherwise, things are pretty much what you might expect in (a place similar to) 14th century Europe.

The Necromancer is a former apothecary who fled the city to practice his dark art in peace. I haven't quite decided what magic will be available to him, but if you're familiar with the canon, that's about right - he can raise the dead, spread a pestilence, etc.

The main character is a mage hunter, of sorts. He's not so much the "great mage slayer of legend" as he is "the best we've got." Situations like this pop up rarely in my world, so few have ever had to deal with such. The main character, having dealt with mages twice previously (not necessarily a Necromancer) has the most experience and thus is chosen to take care of the Necromancer.

The basic idea that I'm trying to convey here is that standard armor (plate, mail, shield, etc.) would be useless against such a foe. At this point in the story, the main character is making preparations and I would like for him to grab one or several items that may (or may not) be useful in the coming fight. Many people in this world have little to no experience with magic, though the main character has dealt with it once or twice. Assuming he has some experience with this sort of thing in the past, what items might the main character bring along with him to protect him against the Necromancer?

**Some additional info from comments:**

- The main character (and some as-yet undetermined party) are sent out to deal with the Necromancer
- They are commissioned by the King to do so, as travelers have started going missing in the area where the Necromancer is believed to live
- The Necromancer has "standard" Necromantic magic available to him. He can raise the undead and cast a number of offensive spells
- The incantations must be uttered, so casting these spells takes time and requires line of sight to the target

Comment: Hello, levelonehuman! Love the screen-name, btw. I'd like to point out that your question, as it currently stands, falls under the close category of "primarily opinion based". The reason for this is because you don't **A)** tell us exactly what the necromancer's location/defenses/offensive powers are, **B)** because you also because you don't tell us what our hero's defenses/offensive powers are, and lastly **C)** because you don't tell us what your success parameters are. You ask how the hero could defend himself, but under what circumstances are they fighting? Why are they fighting?

Comment: If/When your question is put on hold, do not panic. Simply edit it, and the community will vote to reopen it once it meets WB SE standards. Here's some good reading on the site scope: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1

Comment: @AndreiROM I appreciate that, but I suppose that's precisely what I'm looking for. At this point the character is simply making preparations and he doesn't know what he might face, or when. Before he heads out to face what is largely unknown to him and everyone else, he needs to make preparations. Are there any items he might want to take with him?

I will update the question with some additional details

Comment: @AndreiROM Also, plausible options (opinions, as you said) are what I'm after in this case. If this is off-topic, I can close the question, but I'm asking for help in figuring out what (if any) items the main character might find useful in this case.

Comment: I agree with Andrei's reasoning, but I think that makes it too broad.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon - What I would like the OP to tell us is this: I have a mage with X powers hiding in a cave, with fortifications build like so. The perimeter is patrolled by undead legions (200 troops). The mage also has X number of personal bodyguards who taste his food, etc. The Hero must _kill_ the mage. He has no magical powers, but is a skilled fighter/assassin/marksman. The hero will have one or two companions with him, but not benefit from the help of an entire army. What is the best way for the hero to accomplish his goal? Might be a little broad, but we could at least work with that.

Comment: @levelonehuman - **"I can appreciate that but..."** <- the problem here is that there is no "but". That may have sounded mean, so I'll clarify: WB SE has certain rules and regulations (the scope of the site). It's certainly not my prerogative to impose my views and interpretations on your question, but I've been around long enough to know when a question doesn't fall within WB's scope. Your question only has 24 views, and already 2 close votes. This is a pretty good indication that I know what I'm talking about. My guess is that your question will be on hold in an hour or two max

Comment: @levelonehuman - I've read your edits, and I can see where you're trying to go with your question. I don't really have a clear idea on how you might tighten your specs, so I'll describe the issue I'm seeing a little more clearly. Your hero needs to kill this mage, not just convince him to go away, right? So why not simply pack a longbow, locate his lair, and sit around until he gets a clear shot at him? Perfectly valid reasoning, right? But what if the necromancer has roaming patrols of undead around his castle? Well? Does he live in a castle? Does he have guards? An army? Help us help you.

Comment: The King has sent  a bunch of untrained, undisciplied and unwilling adventures to deal with what sounds like a great threat to the city instead of an army? I think the king doesnt like you guys too much. I recommend defecting to the necromancers side and enjoy the dark side till another party of heros come, let them kill the necromance > kill them and take the credit

Comment: As specifically discussed in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), *If your question involves magical elements, you must provide enough details about the magic system in question so that answers may be given that conform to the particular magic system.* I see very little in terms of such detail here, and for that reason there are simply too many possible answers. I have cast a final close vote as too broad, but noting that the question as closed had three "too broad" and two "primarily opinion-based" close votes.

Comment: I would suggest that you either drop by in [chat] (there are usually some regulars in there who would likely be happy to help you out) or even better use our [question sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/635/29) to refine your question such that it can be reopened.

Comment: My question is why people are hunting the necromancer, if he only wants to practice his craft in "peace"? I don't think the main character can be considered a hero in the story (by the readers) for killing an innocent Mage, even if he is a necromancer.

Comment: Good reading: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site?rq=1

Comment: @AndreiROM Although it may not seem as such, I appreciate the effort you (and others) have put into making this question fit in with the context of the site. I'm going to leave this one as-is, and will be posing a question more in line with the scope of this site after having answered some of the questions that have been raised here. Thank you!

Comment: @levelonehuman - I'm very glad to hear you say that, and are very welcomed. One of the issues which WB has run into over and over again is _how_ to educate new users on what a "good" question is. Heck, sometimes _we_ can't even agree. The problem is that most people don't take it well that you criticize their post, or tell them they shouldn't have answered a poorly asked question. So how does one go about spreading this knowledge without discouraging, or offending new users? Difficult balance. I'm glad you weren't discouraged, and look forward to your next post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few methods the hero can take, I will outline as best I can

tl;dr - basically when defending the hero wants to use the counter of the magic the necromancer has used so less energy is wasted (wood > fire, fire > earth kind of thing) hit-and-run tatics would be best as the hero can attack without being attack (at least not easily done right)

### Defensive Scenario 1 - Hero has the advantage

In this situation the hero has the upper hand of a supprise "attack" Now I know you are wanting defensive approaches however @dot_Sp0T "A Good Defense is a Good Offense" would likely be the best way for your hero regardless of how the fight comes to be.

But In the willing of the question I shall explain how a supprise "attack" can bt used for defensive means. A stun/paralysis attack, this could be an eletrical attack or a gas based attack. If the necromance cannot do anything then your hero (and party if he has one) will be unscathed, no better out come in my opinion.

### Defensive Scenario 2 - Hero and Necromancer meet head-on

In this case the Hero and Necromancer will have a <strike>nice</strike> chat, realise they cant come to an agreement and then begin throwing magic at each other. At this point it becomes vital we know what arsenal the hero and necro have, if there is too large a gap in their power the fight becomes one sided but for arguments sake lets say they evenly matched (with the hero slightly less powerful but is willing to go further to save humanity or whatever he is doing).

So the hero is fighting an upwards battle, best thing he can do is use guerrilla tatics/hit-and-run, conserve his own energy and make the necro waste his. **For his defensive magic** if it is just manipulating real world material (Wood/stone/water/fire/air etc etc) then he will need to know each elements counter, IE dont use wood agaisnt fire, he can then either deflect the attack away from himself (or back to the necro if possible) using the least amount of energy possible. Once the necro is sufficently worn our then the hero can move in for the "finishing blow"

### Defensive Scenario 3.1 - The hero is caught off guard

The evil necro has used a underhanded, sly and cheap technique and the hero is in a ... well lets call is a bad situation.

So the hero is wounded, its not fatal but he could have done without the injury agaisnt such a foe.

- If the hero isnt the smartest the best choice would be to charge the necro as it would be the least expected move and the hero is unlikely to make any plans in the few moments he has before the necro has to kill him.
- If the hero is about average intelligence then the best option to him would to "haul-ass" he will know he is in a bad situation and needs a bit of time to think what he can do, this goes back to guerrilla tatics and hit-and-run but with alot more desperation and cussing.
- If the hero is a genius at this sort of thing, I leave it up to him, if I was a genius then I could help however I'm not, he could taunt the necro into making a mistake and taking that oppotunity to counter the necro

---

There are many more scenarios which would take into account terrain, additional party members, what can and cannot be done with magic and so forth but as you havent mentioned anything to do with that I have left it purely about the combat, there is alot of offensive manoeuvre but that is because its alot harder to fight if you soly defend yourself

Comment: I'm sure that your gorilla tactics will prove to be no match for the necromancer.

Comment: Good reading: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/should-we-answer-off-topic-questions/3121#3121

Comment: @AndreiROM since the necro can summon skeletons/undead then it will make it harder but depending how the summon works they are likely to just be mindless zombies that attack anything that moves or move towards sound ... ive yet to see a necromance micro manage all of the summons they have

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was being a bit (a lot :P) sarcastic above. It's "guerrilla" tactics, not "gorilla". It has nothing to do with the animal. That's all that comment was meant to point out.

Comment: @AndreiROM , thats ok, I know my spelling/gramma isnt the best. I also fall flat on my face when people are sarcastic so im glad you pointed it oit for me, I updated the correct term ^^

Answer (score 2):

[The best Defense is a good Offense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_best_defense_is_a_good_offense)

Adhering to this simple but effective rule, the most likely way to get rid of the necromancer would likely be to first [shoot/stun him with a simple firearm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_firearm#Europe) or something similar, a firearm should be uncommon enough for the apothecary to not expect it.
After that it's simply a race of killing him off before he can recover from the shock. Especially assuming that magic users are as scarce as water in the desert.

Comment: I like this, mages are squishy. I'm having a hard time thinking of any trinkets or such that might be useful in this case, but blasting him to bits sounds good.

Comment: @levelonehuman well, gunpowder is pretty much the embodiment hard fantasy in my personal humble opinion

Comment: As far as I know, guns were kind of just starting to pop up in Europe around this time. As it were, I'd prefer to keep with a bow/crossbow. Regardless of firearm or not, the idea of "get him before he gets you" is about what I was looking for. I'd like to wait a while and see if anything else comes up, but thanks again for the answer!

Comment: Good reading: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/should-we-answer-off-topic-questions/3121#3121